# returned 1 exit status, c program

Tags: c, fork, dev-c++

Getting the error as the title says. No idea how to get this code running. I cant seem to find the error.

```
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status



#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>    //NOTE: Added

int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};


int main()
{
    int b[5] = {5,6,7,8,9};
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    int i;
    if(pid == 0){
        for(i = 0; i<5;i++)
            a[i]*=2;
        for(i = 0; i<5;i++)
            b[i]*=2;
    }

    else{

        wait(NULL);
        for(i =0;i<5;i++)
            printf('%d', a[i]);
        for(i =0;i<5;i++)
            printf('%d', b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you need any additional information or help just please commennt and i will fill in with whatever you need

before the error message described above these two messages appear:

```
test.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `fork'
test.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `wait'
```

Comment: `printf('%d', a[i]);` ==> `printf("%d", a[i]);`

Comment: You should have gotten a warning about an incorrect type of argument to `printf` from the compiler before that.

Comment: Error 1 colloquially means "shit happened" and isn't really useful on its own. You need to be looking at the information prior to that error.

Comment: @Thebluefish check the edit. The lines before the error message are shown

Comment: What is the exact command you issue to build this program?

Comment: @AppCodah What OS are you using?

Comment: @Robᵩ No command, i am using devc++ to run the code.

Comment: @Thebluefish Windows 7

Comment: `fork` is not available on Windows. You're going to need a Windows-specific solution for what you're looking to accomplish here.

Comment: @Thebluefish Thank you, i used http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc just to test and it worked fine